Reclassify by table
I'm using IFSAR 5x5 DEM Raster and run a Reclassify by Table with only 5 values 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. Then I converted the reclassified raster into Polygon. When I checked the attribute table the values became 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.
Why is there a "0" even though the values I inputed was only 1 to 5? And when I highlighted the zeros, its a significant area. How to eliminate these zeros?


What is the corresponding value in the IFSAR raster for the area of 0? Normally I'd expect 0 where the IFSAR has NoData, is that an option in your raster?

Please edit your question to specify what GIS software you are using.
